# websocket client intermittently fails to transmit when making rapid calls to socket.send()

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, websocket

I have a websocket server and client.  I am able to establish a connection and transmit messages(data) in both directions.  However, when a client running in a web browser rapidly makes calls to socket.send() some messages are not received by the server.  If I slow down the client calls to socket.send() all messages are received by the server.  Why does the timing of calls to socket.send() have anything to do with intermittently dropping messages?

- The behavior occurs with Chrome, FireFox and Safari running on Win7, Android and iOs.  Thus I don't see this as a browser bug.
- The server is nodejs, but that isn't relevant since the server isn't the problem.
- By rapid calls I mean the calls are being made in a loop controlled by requireAnimationFrame().
- The amount of data in the messages is small, around 40 bytes each.  There are < 10 messages, ie calls to socket.send() in a row.  Thus I don't see how I could be overflowing a TCP buffer.  But maybe?
- The websocket is in 'arraybuffer' mode.
- socket.bufferedAmount === 0 before and after each send, regardless of whether the message is dropped by the client.
- The socket continues to send messages in both directions after a dropped message.  For example, the client will make 10 calls to socket.send(), the server will see all messages except 3 and 7, while the client will see all messages sent by the server.
- I have verified the integrity of the data to just before the call to socket.send().  The client code is calling var tmpArrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer( n ) to create a new buffer before each call to socket.send( tmpArrayBuffer ).  Thus I don't think my client code is overwriting its own buffers.
- There is never a case of a mangled message.  Messages either arrive intact, or they don't arrive at all.  Most messages arrive.
- The old C programmer in me thinks this is a case of over writing a buffer.  But I don't see how that is possible in javascript and given that socket.send() should be the end of my responsibility for the data.
- I am attempting to sniff the TCP traffic between the client and server using MS Message Analyzer.  However this is a challenge because the of the browser XOR with the websocket key means I have to decrypt each message by hand.  Slow and not fun.  Anyone have a better idea?
- My code is part of a larger project which is too large and convoluted to post.  I'm working on a small test stub which may help to debug the problem.  I'll post the stub if/when I get it working.  In any case, the larger project "works" when the calls to socket.send() are spaced out in time, thus I don't think this is a problem with code elsewhere in the project.
- I think this is a problem with my understanding of how to use websockets and/or TCP.
- Another thread suggested anti virus software (stackoverflow question 21191620).  I've tried disabling my antivirus software.  No effect.  Also, the problem is identical on an Android phone and an iTouch, which arn't running antivirus software.

This is the first time in years I have been unable to solve a problem by researching it on the web via sites such as stackoverflow.  I've googled this issue until my fingers are numb. Thus I finally created an account here and posted a question.  Please help!

Comment: "the server isn't the problem" - how do you know this?  Could be the module you're using dropping messages, right?  "I am attempting to sniff the TCP traffic..." - have you looked at the network tab in chrome?  If you click on a websocket connection, you can see the frames your browser thinks have been sent/received.  Would be useful to know if messages are showing up there.  Do you have an `onerror` handler hooked up to the socket?

Comment: - The server is implemented using the "net" module in node.js.  Debug code tells me when data arrives at the server.  I have an onerror handler in the client, it does not fire.  I can see frames in chrome.network, but they don't tell me much.  How do I see the data the browser thinks it sent?

Comment: I do not know for certain the server isn't at fault.  However I don't see how the timing issue could be the servers fault.  Thus I'm trying to look at the tcp traffic hoping to find out if the browser is really transmitting the data.

Comment: Ohhh you're using raw `net`.  Why not, for example, the `ws` module?

Comment: I see something like https://dev-trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/51cc601802ea420dfb00000d/530cfc97fc1d168421783b33/4766b2de5379aaa4a376e5ff61b92a0d/upload_2014-02-26_at_1.14.19_pm.png in the frames tab - green are frames sent by client, white by server.

Comment: In the chrome network tab I can see frames which match the lengths of the messages I am sending, including the messages the server does not receive.  I am new to using the chrome developer tools.  Does this mean the browser sent the tcp data?  If so I guess you are right, the server code must be at fault.

Comment: I'm using raw 'net' because, well I enjoy tinkering and figuring out how things work.

Comment: You are smart.  I am newb.  It looks like node.js is clumping some messages into a single callback.  My code assumes a callback per message.  Now I just have to figure out how to parse the databack node is giving me.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah! That makes sense.  WebSocket messages are built so you can find the end of a message.  Don't assume that a single event will contain an entire message either - messages could very well be split across events.

Comment: I am not sure how to close this question.  The answer is: The browser is sending all tcp data.  The node.js server code is not properly parsing received data into separate "messages".  The server code bug did not become apparent until messages were sent rapidly enough that node.js merged blocks of data in a single callback.

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific cause is [Nagle's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm) (Wikipedia link).

Specifically, if several messages are sent in a short amount of time, TCP may combine some of the messages into the same TCP frame.

This will result in multiple WebSocket (WS) frames in the same IP packet.  A well behaved WS server would read into the TCP frame only as far as the WS frame's header says that there is data.  A well behaved WS server that understand Nagle's Algorithm will then check for another WS frame to decode.

An issue that I've run into when developing a PHP based WS server is, once the server reads up to the end of the first message, if there is any data remaining, the network stack will complain loudly when I try to check for new packets.

A poorly behaved WS server may read beyond where the WS frame says the data ends, and either include the second message's WS frame in the first message's data, or fail in strange and unusual ways.

If you absolutely must have real time communications, the TCP_NODELAY flag is available.  For the sake of most people's networks, though, it's generally considered good manners to let Nagle's Algorithm queue and merge messages.

This is typically a server-side only problem because the vast majority of WS clients are the web browsers, which are already aware of Nagle's Algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in the server, not the client.  Node.js is passing multiple messages in a single callback.  My code assumed a callback per ws message.  This wasn't an issue until messages were passed at a high rate.  Once the server code was modified to parse the individual messages the problem goes away.  Happy days!